# Data normalization from CSV

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-normalization

I am trying to figure out how to normalize some data in a table. No matter how I try I still get repeating groups!! Can any one offer me some guidance with this data?

This is the data that I am trying to normalize:

```
LANDLORD                LANDLORD GROUP                  QUARTER YEAR    ESTIMATED   ACTUAL
Housing Leeds           Yorkshire LL                    3       2013    221         235
Housing Leeds           Yorkshire LL                    2       2014    206 
Manchester housing      Northwest housing associates    3       2012    134         130
Liverpool properties    Northwest housing associates    2       2012    539         592
Liverpool properties    Northwest housing associates    3       2014    567 
Manchester housing      Northwest housing associates    2       2013    157         157
Liverpool properties    Northwest housing associates    2       2014    527 
Housing Leeds           Yorkshire LL                    3       2012    238         240
Liverpool properties    Northwest housing associates    4       2012    585         460
Manchester housing      Northwest housing associates    1       2012    125         136
Manchester housing      Northwest housing associates    3       2014    150 
Liverpool properties    Northwest housing associates    3       2012    569         585
Housing Leeds           Yorkshire LL                    1       2013    195         214
Manchester housing      Northwest housing associates    2       2012    132         140
Manchester housing      Northwest housing associates    2       2014    152 
Liverpool properties    Northwest housing associates    2       2013    555         577
Housing Leeds           Yorkshire LL                    3       2014    215 
Manchester housing      Northwest housing associates    4       2014    114 
Manchester housing      Northwest housing associates    1       2014    140 
Manchester housing      Northwest housing associates    3       2013    160         157
Liverpool properties    Northwest housing associates    3       2013    528         537
Liverpool properties    Northwest housing associates    1       2014    596 
Housing Leeds           Yorkshire LL                    2       2012    226         231
Manchester housing      Northwest housing associates    4       2013    111 
Manchester housing      Northwest housing associates    1       2013    135         136
Housing Leeds           Yorkshire LL                    1       2014    231 
Liverpool properties    Northwest housing associates    4       2013    536 
Manchester housing      Northwest housing associates    4       2012    105         96
Liverpool properties    Northwest housing associates    1       2013    527         560
Housing Leeds           Yorkshire LL                    4       2013    226 
Housing Leeds           Yorkshire LL                    2       2013    198         214
Housing Leeds           Yorkshire LL                    4       2014    235 
Liverpool properties    Northwest housing associates    1       2012    494         536
Housing Leeds           Yorkshire LL                    4       2012    181         197
Liverpool properties    Northwest housing associates    4       2014    568 
Housing Leeds           Yorkshire LL                    1       2012    201         209
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what is your desired result?  It looks like each line is unique, you could create a lookup table(s) for `Landlord` and `Landlord Group` to save some space.

Comment: I think I was over complicating things by trying over normalize. I created a table with Quarter, Estimated and Actual. Then I created another table with Quarter and Year. I was using the Quarter from the first table as a foreign key. I guess I was trying to reduce Quarter and Year from repeating. But your suggestion of using a lookup table sounds much better to me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Goat CO suggested, you could create two reference tables on this one, namely, `Landlord` and `LandLord Group`. And then of course relate it to your main Table.

So, in that case you could have three tables, namely, **LandLord**, **LandLordGroup** and probably **LandRental** tables.

You could probably have these `Tables` and `Fields` then:

```
 Table  : LandLord
 Fields : LandLordID, LandLordName

 Table  : LandLordGroup
 Fields : LandLordGroupID, LandLordGroupName

 Table  : LandRental
 Fields : LandRentalID, LandLordID, LandLordGroupID, Quarter, Year, Estimate
```

Do not take literally the `no repeating groups` in `1NF` (1st Normal Form) rule here because the repeating groups here are now all `foreign keys` from reference tables (i.e. LandLord, LandLordGroup). Additionally notice that I added a `Primary Key` (LandRentalID) now in your main table (i.e. LandRental).

Comment: Thanks both of you for your help. Now this solution is much more simple. I was over complicating things as mentioned in above comment.